# Quicksort bounds

Tags: algorithms, quicksort

I found an implementation of Quicksort [here](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort), and now I cannot understand why it works with those left and right bounds.

Right now the link above is unavailable due to some problems with their hosting provider.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = new int[] {
                10, 3, 2, 5, 4
        };

        System.out.println("array == " + Arrays.toString(array));
        quickSortModified(array, 0, array.length - 1);
        System.out.println("sorted array == " + Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    private static int partition(int arr[], int left, int right) {
        int i = left, j = right;
        int tmp;
        int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot)
                i++;
            while (arr[j] > pivot)
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    private static void quickSortModified(int arr[], int left, int right) {
        int index = partition(arr, left, right);
        if (left < index - 1)
            quickSortModified(arr, left, index - 1);
        if (index + 1 < right)
            // TODO: index + 1 vs index for the bound here.
            quickSortModified(arr, index + 1, right);
    }
}
```

Why should left be less than `index - 1`, not just index?

Why should index (not `index + 1`) be less than right?

For example, on Wikipedia they use `index + 1` for the second recursive call.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried running it by hand on some examples, and then do the same for a modified version of the algorithm the changes made that you have in mind?  That's often the best way to get a feeling for an algorithm.  Alternatively, you can try proving it correct by finding a loop invariant, though this is often more challenging.

Comment: @D.W., I tried many implementations and got confused with different (as I think) approaches they use. E.g., on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort they claim the pivot is in its final position after the partition operation and use the bound [lo, p - 1] and [p + 1, hi]. And the data structure on Wikipedia is not zero-based. [@Raphael told me](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/43561/15063), "The pivot **usually** ends up in its final position after partitioning." Using `index + 1` for the right part, I experienced an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I just have much information in mess.

Comment: BTW, there is a bug in the partition function: `(left + right) / 2` might overflow in very large arrays. Better to use: `left + (right - left) / 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given us the complete picture, but in general, if you are going to call `quickSort` on the slice of the array `lo .. hi`, then there is only need to do so if `lo < hi`; otherwise the array has at most one element and doesn't need to be sorted.